# Saving image information in database or not?

Tags: php, file-upload, relational-database

Lets say I'm building a image gallery using PHP, where users would be able to upload their photos.
Every user would have 1 folder on server side with all their images there.

Now lets say I need to provide information in browser. Users would be able to browse images and should see lots of information about them, like image size, image dimensions, even EXIF information etc.

I could do this in 2 ways:

1. Save all information about image into database when uploading image.
2. Use PHP functions to browse through folder, and get information from every image.

I have something like file manager class, that can do all manipulations with files on server side, like deleteDir, deleteFile, countItems, getFileSize, getDirSize.
And it would be easy to only write one more class that would inspect images, and then I could just upload images, and get their information right from the folders without a need for relation database.

And now the question you all been waiting for is: ... :)

What would be faster, first or second solution? Lets say that site gets loads of traffic. 
What solution would be better if I want it to be fast, and not to stress server to much?

Comment: store images in file system. and store locations in database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually, I got this situation like yours, this is my solution:

> Save all information about image into database when uploading image.

Why?

I tested 2 ways:

> Using php to get the image info for **1000** times.
>
> Getting image info from database for **1000** times.

And the result is :

> Getting image info from database is faster and faster.

Last but not least:

> What would you do if you want to do a image info analystics?

If you save all info in database ,you can easily get them and analyse them ,but if you using php to get the info? it's hard to image.

So, just save all information about image into database when uploading image.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

storing it in the database once 
reading the data from the database and store it in cache,

redoing things always costs especially if it happens all the time

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of these images, you probably want to show thumbnails instead of the original when people are browsing, which means you need to generate them. I would generate the thumbnail on upload and grab all the file info. Then save the file info in the database and put the original and thumbnail in the file system. If you get a lot of traffic, throw memcache on there too.

Answer (score 0):

Storing data in separate places has a way of creating maintenance headache. I would just serialize the metadata for images in each folder and dump it to a file there. If you use gzip compression on the file, retrieval and storage should be very fast.